# How to show $(s+t)^p\le 2^{p-1}(s^p + t^p)$ for $p\gt1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

How to show $(s+t)^p\le 2^{p-1}(s^p + t^p)$ for $p\gt1$

I know how to prove for $s+t=1$ by $\min\lbrace t^p+(1-t)^p\rbrace=2^{1-p}$. But I do not know to how to generalize for $s+t\gt0$.

Could you please help?

Comment: I guess you also require s,t greater or equal to zero. Then from Jensen's inequality, the mean of the p power is greater or equal to the p power of the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(s+t)^p\le 2^{p-1}(s^p + t^p) 
\Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \le (\frac{s}{s+t}) ^p + (\frac{t}{s+t}) ^p $$
Let $ u = \frac{s}{s+t} $, then this is equivalent to:

$$ 2^{1-p} \le u^p + (1-u) ^p $$

Answer (score 4):

The inequality is - per division by $(s+t)^p > 0$ - equivalent to

$$1 \leqslant 2^{p-1}\left(\left(\frac{s}{s+t}\right)^p + \left(\frac{t}{s+t}\right)^p\right),$$

which is the special case you already proved.